# How to ensure all changes in every controls applied to the DataSet before the data save to the database?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

When I develop using Delphi I always call DataSet.CheckBrowseMode() to allow bound controls to apply its pending changes to the DataSet.  I've been looking for similar way in .NET

I've tried

```
// When the user press Ctrl-S 
// Apply any pending edit
this.TheDataBindingSource.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit();
// then save the data
this.SaveData();
```

Unlike Delphi DataSet.CheckBrowseMode(), this code does not has any effect when there are pending changes inside a TextBox.  My user has to move the focus away from the textbox via <"TAB"> before pressing Ctrl-S to save the data.

Comment: This is a very good document on this topic:

http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/Data%20Binding/DataBinding%20FAQ.doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158374.aspx), if you Validate the Form, it will cause all controls to push their current data back to the data source.

```
// When the user press Ctrl-S 
// Apply any pending edit
this.Validate();  // assuming this is the Form...
// set the DataSource of the BindingSource to null,
// otherwise, the BindingSource immediately calls
// BeginEdit() automatically
this.TheDataBindingSource.DataSource = null;
this.TheDataBindingSource.EndEdit();
// then save the data
this.SaveData();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.BindingContext[dataTableVariableHere].EndCurrentEdit();
```

or if you use BindingSource to bind data to your controls:

```
foreach(Component c in this.components.Components)
    if(c is BindingSource)
        (c as BindingSource).EndEdit();
```

Comment: calling EndEdit would make DataRowView (or other IEditableObjecT) push the row to data-store.  However, sometime data is pending on the control itself.  Calling Form.Validate before BindingSource.EndEdit is the perfect solution.